# Converting integer into formatted string

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstring, type-conversion

How would I format an integer when I convert it to a string? For example:

```
NSString *date = [NSString stringWithFormat:
       @"...somestuff... %+02d00", ...., gmtOffset];
```

The above does not work properly. What I want is, for example, +0200 to appear. I should think that %+02d would convert my integer 2 into "+02". But it does no happen, I get "+2". Why is this? Am I doing something wrong or is some formatting not supported?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: I finally got it. Works for both positive and negative numbers and adds the leading zeros. Hope it helps.

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%+03d00", 2];
NSLog(@"%@", str);
```

Comment: Well what if I want it to be -2? The + is supposed to force a + or - in front of the number, and this solution gets me "+-02"....

Comment: @radiopaque Edited my answer. It's not the cleanest code, but it works.

Comment: @radiopaque I've done some debugging and finally found the best answer. Hope it's what you've been looking for.

Comment: Yes! It's a bit counter-intuitive (to me), but the sign counts as a character. So for two actual digits, plus a sign, you'd need THREE characters as in your answer. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Yes Adam is right:

```
  NSString *date = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                  @"%+03d00",2];
NSLog(@"date %@",date);
```

Comment: Yes it's 3 decimal places and not 2

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says, that there is a + as modifier. But I don't know how to exactly place/use it.

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html

`+    The result of a signed conversion shall always begin with a sign ( '+' or '-' ). The conversion shall begin with a sign only when a negative value is converted if this flag is not specified.`

Link in apple documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html

Comment: I couldn't get this work. It does add the sign properly, but doesn't add the leading zeros. I'm curious if there is a solution for this.